# Result always 0 when using an Integer returned from switch statement in another method's calculation

Tags: java, switch-statement

My program is designed to assign an integer value based on a class size that the user inputs (S, M, L, X).  Then, in a later method, I use this value to calculate the remaining seats available in the class.  This issue that I'm having is that, in spite of the program running, the value returned is always zero, no matter what class size the user inputs or the number of students entered as being registered already.

The program includes a few other unrelated steps, so I've isolated the aforementioned methods for ease of reference but I can post my complete code if this is easier.

My code to assign the integer value:

```
public static int courseSize() {
   System.out.print("Please enter the course size (possible values are: 
   S, M, L, or X):");
   size = console.next().charAt(0);
   switch(size) {
      case 'S': totalSeats = 25;
                break;
      case 'M': totalSeats = 32;
                break;
      case 'L': totalSeats = 50;
                break;
      case 'X': totalSeats = 70;
                break;
      default: System.out.println("Please enter S, M, L, or X");
   }//Close switch statement
   console.nextLine();
   return totalSeats;
}//Close courseSize
```

This is the code for obtaining the number of students registered and calculating the number of seats available:

```
public static void numStudents() {
  System.out.print("How many students are currently registered for this course? ");
  studentsReg = console.nextInt();
}//Close numStudents method

//This method returns the number of open seats remaining
public static int calcAvail () {
    openSeats = (totalSeats - seatsTaken);
    return openSeats;
} //Close calcAvail method
```

This is the output for collecting the user input.  You can see the user entered L (50 seats) and 13 students are registered.

[image: User Input Prompt]

However, you can see in the below output that it states there are 0 remaining seats.

[image: Output]

All of the variables in this code are declared under my class as public, static variables.

Any thoughts as to why my calculation isn't working?  I'm leaning toward the issue being my switch statement because it uses a char as input and then stores it as an integer; however, the output is still printing out the correct number to the screen.

Comment: show example output and expected output. what do you mean by "why my calculation isn't working" and "the output is still printing out the correct number to the screen"

Comment: after you get the number of studentsReg value, make sure you call console.nextLine(); to clear the end of line character left by nextInt(), or else the call to courseSize() will return 0

Comment: I updated the question to include the output!

Comment: `totalSeats = 50` Check. --- `studentsReg = 13` Check. --- `openSeats = (totalSeats - seatsTaken)` Huh? What is value of `seatsTaken`?

Comment: What variable is being printed in that line? How is that variable assigned? ***Show your code***. If it is `openSeats`, then perhaps you **never call `calcAvail()`**, but that's a guess, because you haven't shown the relevant code. --- http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ *(no code = missing code)*

Comment: Andreas, I truly appreciate the feedback.  I hadn't considered that my entire code was necessary for you to see the true issue but now I definitely see the need.  I actually hadn't called calcAvail(); so this was the problem.  Thank you so much for not only helping me see my error but also educating me on properly posting questions!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move this `console.nextLine();` in `numStudents()`

default is missing break

```
default: System.out.println("Please enter S, M, L, or X");
    break;
}

return totalSeats;
}
```

You can do

```
default: System.out.println("Incorrect entry");
    courseSize();
    break;
}
```

and

`openSeats = (totalSeats - seatsTaken);` should be

```
openSeats = (totalSeats - studentsReg );
```

Comment: I tried moving console.nextLine(); to where you suggested but then the program doesn't progress to asking for the size.

Comment: How is this answer in any way related to why "Number of seats available" is 0? User correctly entered `L` and code correctly assigned the total number of seats from that, so the `default` case is of no consequence.

Comment: How does replacing `seatsTaken` with `studentsReg` explain why `openSeats` might be 0? If `seatsTaken` is unassigned (we can only assume since nothing is shown about it), then `seatsTaken` would have calculated to 50, not 0, so simply changing that value is unlike *the* answer.

Comment: OP is to provide that (All of the variables in this code are declared under my class as public, static variables.) or he is doing `seatstaken = totalSeats ` perhaps . and break is not mandated but its good practice https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/201777/break-on-default-case-in-switch

Comment: Thank you both for your assistance.  It was both that I mistakenly used the incorrect variable of seatsTaken instead of studentsReg, and also that I missed calling the calcAvail() method.  

I'm new to programming, and you've both been helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I would clear the EOL character left by your call to nextInt() in your numStudents() with the following code

```
public static void numStudents() {
    System.out.print("How many students are currently registered for this course? ");
    //code A
    studentsReg = console.nextInt();
    console.nextLine();
    //or
    //code B
    studentsReg = Integer.parseInt(console.nextLine());
}//Close numStudents method
```

Then I would wrap a while() around your switch to make sure your user has to input a valid selection or retry, and use nextLine() instead of next() which also leaves behind an EOL character ('\n').

```
public static int courseSize() {
       boolean validInput = false;
       while(!validInput)
       {
           validInput = true;
           System.out.print("Please enter the course size (possible values are: S, M, L, or X):");
           size = console.nextLine().charAt(0);
           switch(size) {
           case 'S': totalSeats = 25;
                    break;
           case 'M': totalSeats = 32;
                    break;
           case 'L': totalSeats = 50;
                    break;
           case 'X': totalSeats = 70;
                    break;
           default: System.out.println("Incorrect Value Entered, Please enter S, M, L, or X");
                   validInput = false;
                   break;
           }//Close switch statement
       }
       return totalSeats;
}//Close courseSize
```

Comment: How is this answer in any way related to why "Number of seats available" is 0? Changed code will not cause a different value to be assigned to `studentsReg`, and since user correctly entered `L` and code correctly assigned the total number of seats from that, the `default` case and your new loop is of no consequence to what is being asked in the question.